# How can we compare data with previous date data in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, window-functions

Please anyone help me to write sql query that will give filtered data with previous date values comparison.

For example

```
symbol  date        pivot   
SBIN    2020-06-05  184.533 
SBIN    2020-06-04  174.4   
SBIN    2020-06-03  175.6   
SBIN    2020-06-02  169.583 
SBIN    2020-06-01  168.267 
SBIN    2020-05-29  159.467 
SBIN    2020-05-28  159.1   
SBIN    2020-05-27  156.733 
SBIN    2020-05-26  151.6   
SBIN    2020-05-22  151.967 
SBIN    2020-05-21  153.2   
SBIN    2020-05-20  153.267
```

i need query to find the list of stocks if prev day pivot is less than current day pivot

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you want?

Comment: And what is your date column type?

Comment: date column type is date

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
select t*
from (
    select t.*, lag(pivot) over(order by symbol order by date) lag_pivot
    from mytable t
) t
where pivot < lag_pivot
```

This gives you all rows whose "previous" `pivot` is greater than the current one (along with the value of the previous pivot, in column `lag_pivot`).

In earlier versions, one approach is a correlated subquery:

```
select t*
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        (
            select t1.pivot 
            from mytable t1 
            where t1.symbol = t.symbol and t1.date < t.date
            order by t1.date desc limit 1
        ) lag_pivot
    from mytable t
) t
where pivot < lag_pivot
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this query

select * from table t1 where t1.pivot > (select pivot from table t2 where t2.date = DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))